# Python cx_Oracle ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Im attempting to import cx_Oracle and it outputs the error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Im doing this on a win 2003 server with python 2.7 and cx_Oracle 5.1, installed from the .msi.  Oracle 10g (3 instances) exist on the same server.  Looking at other questions, I have validated that ORACLE_HOME is set, and the path to the bin dir is also set.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using ([Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com)) on the cx_oracle lib should make it clear very fast what is missing.

If you cannot use that, a typical guess would be the oracle client libs oraclntsh not being accessible.

Comment: Dependency walker is showing some issues with the OCI.DLL file.  A couple of the functions needed are listed as 'red'.  Im going to try and use an older version of cx_Oracle to see if it will go better w/ my oracle install.

Comment: Is there a FAQ or other doc that tells me what version of OCI.DLL I need to have?  Using older versions of cx_Oracle has not paid off